# Why async.series doesn't work in REPL for the code below?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, concurrency

```
         request(source_url).pipe(async.series([
             function() {
               fs.createWriteStream(path_for_downloads + path.basename(source_url));
             },
             function() {
               done(null);
             }
           ]);
         );
```

It waits for unclosed bracket...

```
...              );
...
```

This works:

```
async.series([
                 function() {
                   fs.createWriteStream(path_for_downloads + path.basename(source_url));
                 },
                 function() {
                   done(null);
                 }
               ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request(source_url).pipe(async.series([
         function() {
           fs.createWriteStream(path_for_downloads + path.basename(source_url));
         },
         function() {
           done(null);
         }
       ]); //close the array, close async.series call, OOPS don't want a semi there
     ); //close the pipe call
```

That's your bug I think. However, this snippet has a bunch of other problems. I think you want something more like:

```
var stream = request(source_url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path_for_downloads + path.basename(source_url));
stream.on('end', done);
stream.on('error', done);
```